# Keras import confusion?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to follow along with the code from [Saul Dobilas's blog on DCGANs](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-convolutional-gan-how-to-use-a-dcgan-to-generate-images-in-python-b08afd4d124e).

I have a Tensorflow-gpu conda environment that I'm running the code from. When I try & run it thought the following error is thrown,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\DeepConvGanExample.py", line 10, in <module>
    print('Tensorflow/Keras: %s' % keras.__version__) # print version
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py", line 62, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py", line 45, in _load
    module = importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
```

So I opened up a python interpreter & typed the following lines,

```
from tensorflow import keras
keras.__version__
```

And I get a similar traceback,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py", line 62, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py", line 45, in _load
    module = importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
```

OK so I closed the interpreter & opened a new one & typed,

```
import tensorflow.keras as keras
keras.__version__
```

Which gives,

```
'2.6.0'
```

What's going on here?

SOLUTION :: I had the wrong version of TensorFlow installed.

Comment: You have multiple python interpreters installed and keras is installed in only one of them.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy when I `conda list python` there is only one version of python listsed

Comment: Please help us to know the installed `TensorFlow` and `python` version for this specific 'tf-gpu' virtual environment of your system to understand the issue better. You can check this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native) to verify the installation process. Thank you.